# Where does tracking data related to Google Play Campaign Measurement go?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have an android app which uses [Google Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to send tracking data to a specific [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) account (let's say account **A**).

The same app is published through a separate Google Play account (account **B**).

Now, I am confused as to where will be the campaign measurement data go (account A or account B?).

Could anyone clarify?

Comment: botteeaap Answer is correct. Analytics reporting is only based on the tracker id. Each hit is send to the tracker that is specified in the &tid param and there is not authenticated in any way. Anyone can send data to any tracker id as long as they know the tracking number.

Comment: Accepting the answer now would be a good thing :)

Comment: Thank you @botteaap. I waited to publish the app and test with the real case. Your answer is correct indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be sent to the account for which the tracking id is for. The account that is used for publishing the app is not related to the analytics data.

If the tracking id is for account A, then publishing with account B won't matter whatsoever and account A will be used for the tracking data.